# OHLC of Multiple Scrips Using Pandas Resample function

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-resample, ohlc

I have ticks data of 2 scrips (scrip_names are abc and xyz).  Since the ticks data is at a "second" level, I want to convert this to OHLC (Open, High, Low, Close) at 1 Minute level.

When the ticks data contains only 1 scrip, I use the following code (OHLC of Single Scrip.py) to get the OHLC at 1 Minute level.  This code gives the desired result.

Code:

```
import os
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ticks=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\tech\Downloads\ticks.csv')

ticks=pd.DataFrame(ticks)
#ticks=ticks.where(ticks['scrip_name']=="abc")
#ticks=ticks.where(ticks['scrip_name']=="xyz")

ticks['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(ticks['timestamp'])

ticks=ticks.set_index(['timestamp'])

ohlc_prep=ticks.loc[:,['last_price']]

ohlc_1_min=ohlc_prep['last_price'].resample('1min').ohlc().dropna()

ohlc_1_min.to_csv(r'C:\Users\tech\Downloads\ohlc_1_min.csv')
```

Result:

[image: single_scrip_result]

However, when the ticks data contains more than 1 scrip, this code doesn't work.  What modifications should be done to the code to get the following result (filename:  expected_result.csv) which is grouped by scrip_name.

**Expected Result**:

[image: expected_result]

Here is the link to ticks data, python code for single scrip, result of single scrip, and desired result of multiple scrips:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y3jngm94hqAW_IJm-FAsl3SArVhnjGJE/view?usp=sharing

Any help is much appreciated.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `groupby` like:

```
ticks['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(ticks['timestamp'])
ticks=ticks.set_index(['timestamp'])

ohlc_1_min=ticks.groupby('scrip_name')['last_price'].resample('1min').ohlc().dropna()
```

Or:

```
ohlc_1_min=(ticks.groupby(['scrip_name', 
                           pd.Grouper(freq='1min', level='timestamp')])['last_price']
                 .ohlc()
                 .dropna())
```